# Saving datefield through django to Postgresql returns format error

Tags: django, postgresql, datefield

I'm trying to save date formatted as dd/mm/yyyy from a view using Django to a postgresql table. I get the following error:

```
ValidationError: [u"'2014/01/30' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

how can i change the format of a specific table or the entire database?

I've tried:`ALTER DATABASE myDb SET datestyle TO "ISO, YMD";`

then when i run `SHOW lc_ctype;` i get:

```
lc_ctype   
-------------
en_US.UTF-8
```

and `SELECT current_date;` returns

```
  date    
------------
 2014-01-29
```

So it looks good, what raise the question if the error is in Django

my views.py looks like this:

```
logEntry, created = Logs.objects.get_or_create(entrydate=request_data['entryDate'], message=request_data['message'])
logEntry.save()
```

and my models.py

```
class Logs(models.Model):
   entrydate= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making changes on the db, I would recommend changing your view so that your date is correctly parsed into a datetime. Additionally, saving it as a timezone aware datetime object can be done as follows:

```
# views
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime


entrydt = datetime.strptime(request_data['entryDate'], "%Y/%m/%d")
entrydt = entrydt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())
logEntry, created = Logs.objects.get_or_create(entrydate=entrydt, 
                                               message=request_data['message'])
logEntry.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have DateTimeField instead DateField in your model.
This error message in DateTimeField
Change DateTimeField -> DateField

Comment: if it's must in YYYY-MM-DD format then i think '2014/01/30'.replace('/','-'). But it's ugly